# Testing- rspec Hartl Tutorial, Chapter 5.33

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

I keep getting the same two failures for a test trying to create a signin page.

**Here is the error message:** $ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb
FF

Failures:

1) User pages signup page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `|' for "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App":String
     # ./app/helpers/application_helper.rb:9:in`full_title'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2148911516627374684_2168968760'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:8:in`block (3 levels) in '

2) User pages signup page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `|' for "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App":String
     # ./app/helpers/application_helper.rb:9:in`full_title'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2148911516627374684_2168968760'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:8:in`block (3 levels) in '

Finished in 0.17668 seconds
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:10 # User pages signup page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:11 # User pages signup page

**And here is the file user_pages_spec.rb**

require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

subject { page }

describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

```
it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign up') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
```

end
end

**here is the file application_helper.rb:**

module ApplicationHelper

```
  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title}" | "#{page_title}"
    end
  end
end
```

**here is the file routes.rb**
        SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
          get "users/new"

```
  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'

  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

I've been stuck on this for quite a bit so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rails error messages it gives you here are pretty descriptive.

If we look at the line

```
undefined method `|' for "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App":String # ./app/helpers/application_helper.rb:9:in full_title
```

It's telling us it can't find a method called `|` for the String `"Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"` on line 9 of application_helper.rb in the `full_title` method definition. If we got to that line we can see

```
 "#{base_title}" | "#{page_title}"
```

Which ruby interprets as "run the method | on the result of "#{base_title}" (which in this case evaluates to the String "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App") with the argument "#{page_title}". Since Strings don't have a '|' method, it returns an "undefined method" error.

To fix, just change the line to

```
 "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
     "#{base_title}" | "#{page_title}"
```

Is the culprit.

I'll break down the error message for you (you'll want to get good at reading these):

```
 ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method |' for "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App":String #
```

What this says is that the ActionView templatings system ran into trouble running your helper.  Specifically, it says you've tried to call an undefined method called '|' (the name of the method is the pipe character) on an object of class String.

If you look in the docs for the String class, [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html), you'll see that the method '|' is not in the list of available methods.

My *guess* is that you're trying to concat these together and include the pipe character, like for a breadcrumb.  In which case you just have to enclose the whole line in quotes, like this:

```
     "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
```

Good luck!